# linux bash: when opening xterm with -e, the varaibles are not getting defined

Tags: linux, bash, xterm

I am trying a simple xterm command:

```
xterm -hold -e "hare=0;echo $hare"
```

it will open xterm with blank

What i observed is variable hare is not getting defined inside the -e quotes

where as:

```
hare=0;xterm -hold -e "echo $hare"
```

it opens an xterm showing 0

i have to define variables in the -e quotes and do something. Is it possible or not. I want xterm to access the outside variables and also the variables defined in the -e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are expanded inside double-quoted strings, so the variable is being expanded by the original shell, not the shell in the `xterm`. Use single quotes.

```
xterm -hold -e 'hare=0; echo $hare'
```

If you assign the variable in the original shell, you need to export it so it will become an environment variable that's inherited by child processes:

```
hare=0
export hare
xterm -e 'echo $hare'
```

Comment: then the problem is the outside variables are not accessible. Now `hare=0;xterm -hold -e 'echo $hare'` shows blank.

Comment: You need to export the variable to make it an environment variable.

Comment: i will be running mulitple shell scripts at a time. Will they not be overlaping with each other.

Comment: Exporting only affects that process and child processes, not the processes running other scripts.

Comment: thank you. I think i can try it now. Else i am not sure it variable are not accessible.

Comment: also how to export in case i am using something like `while read -r line`. If i want to access the $line variable inside xterm

Comment: `export line` will export the variable after you assign it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153037/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-barmar).